# insert content of xlsx in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, xlsx

I'm trying to insert a content of an xlsx file in mongodb using java,First I parsed the file and stored the header in a map, then I parsed the rest of it and insert it in mongodb ( document.put(heater name, value ) )
here is my code :

public class CsvToBson {
    private static List map= new ArrayList();

```
    public void parserResult(String outputs_reports) throws IOException {
        try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        outputs_reports));
                // Create workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                // get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Feuil1");
                int rownum = 0;
                // Iterate through each row one by one
                int i=0;
                Row row = sheet.getRow(rownum++);
                for (Cell cell : row)
                   {
                       map.add(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue());
                       i++;

                   }

               for ( String b: map){
                   System.out.println("entete : "+b);
                   }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error on read or open file !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in XSLSX Parser !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();

                }
    }


    public void parserResult2(String outputs_reports2, List<String> map, DBCollection collection) throws IOException {
        try {
                BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        outputs_reports2));
                // Create workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                // get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Feuil1");
                int rownum = 1;
                // Iterate through each row one by one
                int i=1;
                Row row2 = sheet.getRow(rownum++);

                while (row2 != null) {

                    for (Cell cell : row2) {
                        DBObject object= new BasicDBObject();
                        switch ( cell.getCellType()){
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        document.put(map.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        collection.insert(document);
                        break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        document.put(map.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        collection.insert(document);
                        break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        document.put(map.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getStringCellValue());
                        collection.insert(document);
                        break;


                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error on read or open file !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in XSLSX Parser !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }




  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

      CsvToBson a = new CsvToBson();
      String name= "Test1.xlsx";
      a.parserResult(name);
      DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("mydb");

       //get a single collection 
       DBCollection dbcollection = db.getCollection("Test");
       a.parserResult2(name, map, dbcollection);
  }
```

}

but i get this error message :

```
Error in XSLSX Parser !!!
com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.Test index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5733013034646e0b5030b9d2') }'
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.convertBulkWriteException(BaseWriteOperation.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.access$300(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:146)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:192)
    at Parser.CsvToBson.parserResult2(CsvToBson.java:93)
    at Parser.CsvToBson.main(CsvToBson.java:128)
```

Comment: try to add _id as new id field in inserted

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you provide me an example please ?